# why windeplotqt failed:Warning: Unable to read \mkspecs\qconfig.pri?

Tags: qt, mingw

I am developing a project in QT, when I want to use Windeployqt to wrap my exe.

> error:Warning: Unable to read \mkspecs\qconfig.pri comes out

I execute Eindeployqt in "QT5.1.1 for Desktop(Mingw 4.8.3)", I checked the `qconfig.pri` exsited in
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\mkspecs\qconfig.pri

I have added environment variable, can anyone help on this?

Comment: `\mkspecs\qconfig.pri` is an absolute path that doesn't seem right

Comment: @BrechtSanders yes, but i do nothing since i installed qt, can you let me know how to set the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would do this with environment variable

```
QMAKESPEC=C:\SOMEPATH\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++
```

or in your case probably:

```
QMAKESPEC=C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\mkspecs
```

though normally it should be a folder below mkspecs specifying your platform (`win32-g++` in my first example).

Comment: Thankd Brecht. I think it should be environment variable problem, but after setting QMAKESPEC, still not work

Answer (score 0):

The windeploy tool will use the paths provided from qmake.
Assuming that you are in the bin folder of your qt installation.
All "important" paths can be seen with:
`qmake -query`

In your case you will see that all paths have the wrong location.
You have to add a qt.conf file.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html

with the following content:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = ..
```

Now, running `qmake -query` should return correct paths. Also the windeploy tool should be able to find the correct paths.